# Is the subjunctive always a verb?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I need a bit of help with the subjunctive mood here. I was reading Shakespeare's A Midsummer Night's Dream when I came across this line.

'Weele rest vs Hermia, if you thinke it good'

I was wondering if 'it' is a subjunctive. It's not really a verb though.

Comment: The subjunctive is "be,"  meant to be understood for the sake of the poetry/tone of the dialogue.

Comment: It could be, as in "... if you think (that) it be good". But not in "... if you think (that) it is good". Who knows?

Comment: "Subjunctive" is one of several *moods* of verbs.  (The others are *indicative* and *imperative*.)  **It** is a pronoun.

Comment: Indicative does no work, so is not needed, and imperative is not a mood but a clause type. Mood in Present-day English is marked by the modal auxiliaries.

Comment: One sees here how useless the concept of "subjunctive" is, even to mention. It's used as a magic word to substitute for explanation. Whisper "it's subjunctive" and the room hushes in awe.

Answer (score -1):

Subjunctive is a mood, and can only apply to verbs.